# A question on composition of polynomial functions

Tags: polynomials

Let $x\in R^n$ and $f(x)$ be any polynomial. Is there a set of polynomial functions: $f_1$, $f_2$,... $f_k$, with each in the form of: $f_i(x) = g_i(x_{1:(n-1)})+h_i(x_n)$ such that $f = f_1\circ f_2...\circ f_k$? Here $g_i$ and $h_i$ are arbitrary polynomial functions on $R^{n-1}$ and $R$ respectively. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this composition make sense? Aren't polynomials real or complex valued? Than you can't compose them if the value of one polynomial doesn't match the "type" of the argument of the next. It's a matter of whether or not the image of one function is contained in the domain of the next.

Comment: It should be an issue in this problem: all the polynomials are defined on $R^n$ and so they are all real-valued.

Comment: Then, for example, $f_1\circ f_2$ doesn't make sense. The value of $f_2$ is a real number, so how can $f_1(f_2(\textrm{anything}))$ be meaningful?